# How can I synchronize the authenticated status of different components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've been stuck in this situation for a long time. I was working on an App by React, and in my homepage, I have a navigation bar and another component. What I want to do here is when I login/log out, my navigation bar and my other components will synchronously change. But actually, when I click login/log out in my navigation bar, only the bar change, the other components stay the same until I reload the page. How can I make the login status global? So that every components can change synchronously? I really appreciate your help!

`MainPage.js`

```
const MainPage = () => {
  const [isAuth, setAuth] = React.useState(
    window.localStorage.getItem("isAuth")
  );
  const handleLogOut = () => {
    setAuth(false);
    window.dataLayer.push({
      event: "Log Out",
      user: "Anonymous",
      timezone: "Chicago",
    });
    window.localStorage.clear();
    window.alert("You have succesfully logged out!");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Navigation bar */}
      <Container
        isAuth={isAuth}
        currentPage="Main"
        onLogin={() => {
          setAuth(true);
        }}
        onLogOut={handleLogOut}
      />

      {/* Body */}

      <CardAlign>
        {food.map((foodItem) => (
          <Card foodItem={foodItem} key={`${foodItem.id}`} isAuth={isAuth} />
        ))}
      </CardAlign>

      {/* Buttons */}
      <Buttons isAuth={isAuth} currentPage="Main" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

`isAuth` and `setAuth` are the hooks I use to define the login state. **As you can see here the isAuth didn't update synchronously in `Card` and `Buttons` when changes happened in Container**

`Container.js`

```
const Container = ({ isAuth, currentPage, onLogin, onLogOut }) => {
  return (
    <Header>
      <NavbarDiv>
        {!isAuth && <Login label="Login" onLogin={onLogin} />}
        {isAuth && <LogOut label="Log Out" onLogOut={onLogOut} />}
        {isAuth && <ChangeUser />}
        {isAuth && currentPage !== "Cart" && <Cart />}
        {isAuth && currentPage !== "Profile" && <Profile />}
      </NavbarDiv>
    </Header>
  );
};
```

**`Container.js` is my navigation bar, which worked properly.**

I would really really appreciate your help! Please tell me what's the problem and how I can fix it! Thank you for your time!

Comment: You are passing isAuth, onLogin and onLogOut to Container but then ignore them and instead create them in Container again. The code would work if you just use isAuth, onLogin and onLogOut from props in Container.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I try to modify the code(as updated in the original text) but then after I logged in, the 'login' and 'log out' button just disappeared in my nav bar. Can you tell me how to fix it? Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```js
const Container = ({ isAuth, onLogin, onLogOut }) => {
  //using isAuth, onLogin and onLogout from props
  return isAuth ? (
    <button onClick={onLogOut}>log out</button>
  ) : (
    <button onClick={onLogin}>log in</button>
  );
};
const Buttons = ({ isAuth }) => {
  return (
    <h4>buttons: {isAuth ? 'logged in' : 'logged out'}</h4>
  );
};
const App = () => {
  const [isAuth, setAuth] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <Container
        isAuth={isAuth}
        currentPage="Main"
        onLogin={() => {
          setAuth(true);
        }}
        onLogOut={() => setAuth(false)}
      />
      <Buttons isAuth={isAuth} currentPage="Main" />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Yes yes I think I just make a typo just then. Your answer really helps! Thank you for helping me!!!!!!!!!!!!Have a great day

Answer (score 1):

You should use a util.js file to handle all operations on login & log out, you should export a function to check the login state, is you use an internal state to handle this then you'll need to pass in deep this state as a prop to each child.

You should use a global state handler as Redux. Or use PassportJS or Iron-Session.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation! I've solved the problem now and will try to learn Redux in the future!